# how to install opencv 4.x with python 3 and opencv 3.x with python 2.7 in Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

I installed OpenCV 3.3.1 with python 2.7 (GPU), but I tried to install  OpenCV4.x with Python3.

I followed this post [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/installing-deep-learning-frameworks-on-ubuntu-with-cuda-support/)

Output `find /usr/local/lib/ -type f -name "cv2*.so"` is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: I used this comment: mkvirtualenv virtual-py3 -p python3  and change to (virtual-py3) redhwan@redhwan:~$ am I right?